# Why does 'stream' implement 'pipe' when only stream.Readable are able to pipe?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, stream

This is quite confusing behavior when learning about streams/http on NodeJS. By default intellisense will auto-complete `pipe` on `http.ClientRequest` and `http.ServerResponse` , this is misleading as it doesn't make sense to pipe a writable stream.

To follow up: from the [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html), it appears that `http.ClientRequest`  and `http.ServerResponse` extend `<Stream>` , and `http.IncomingMessage` extends `<stream.Readable>`. But, if we examine the source code, it appears that `ClientRequest extends OutgoingMessage extends stream.Writable` and `ServerResponse extends OutgoingMessage extends stream.Writable`, and `IncomingMessage extends stream.Readable`.
So, I would expect `http.ClientRequest instanceof stream.Writable` to be `true` and `http.ServerResponse instanceof stream.Writable` to be `true`. But this is not the case.

The test:

```
http.createServer((request, response) => {
    request instanceof http.IncomingMessage // => true
    request instanceof stream.Readable // => true
    request instanceof stream.Stream // => true
    response instanceof http.OutgoingMessage // => true
    response instanceof stream.Writable // => false ?
    response instanceof stream.Stream // => true
});
```

```
const request = http.request();
request instanceof http.OutgoingMessage // => true
request instanceof stream.Writable // => false ?
request instanceof stream.Stream // => true
```

I am clearly missing something, but it is not yet obvious to me. Any input is greatly appreciated.